# Performance drop when switching between applications on iOS 9

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, ios9

Is anyone else experiencing choppy animations with Cordova applications running on iOS 9? My app uses Cordova 3.6.3 and is built with the Xcode 7 GM. The application uses a UIWebview. The performance drop occurs when exiting my app and opening another. Upon resuming my application, all of my CSS animations are choppy. But if I exit and reopen my app, all CSS animations are fine.

Comment: Did you take any measurements using the time profiler instrument?

Comment: I am having the same problem with my application. I spent so much time working out the lag and I'm using all 3D transformation animations on the CPU. The animations were completely lag free before I updated to iOS 9. What is going on?